# JComponent clipping through JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

this is my first post in Stack Overflow.
I'm a beginner to Java and Swing, and currently i was working in a project about sorting in JFrame.

I found a problem when working with JPanel and JComponent. Essentially I have clipping problem with JComponent like JButton and JRadioButton where when hovered it will switch to its 'hovered' state, even when they are obstructed by JPanel overlapping it.

[image: This is a screenshot of the clipping problem in the running program]

Comment: Post the code for your UI. Without code, you're asking us to guess at what's going on, which is a massive waste of everyone's time.

Comment: This is the full code of the one JFrame: [link](https://www.paste.org/flat/101990)

Comment: Don't ever use absolute layout. Learn to use a layout manager like GridBagLayout. You probably have to mix multiple nested layouts to get what you want.

Comment: *when hovered it will switch to its 'hovered' state, even when they are obstructed by JPanel overlapping it.* - correct. When a mouse hovers over a button, the button is repainted because of the rollover effect. This is standard Java painting. The question is why would you ever have a panel over top of the button? Seems like you have a problem with the layout.

Comment: I just want to streamline the layout so all the program's features would fit in one class. Is that wrong?